# Generating consecutive numbers with Python

Tags: python

I want to generate sequential numbers using python and save them in .txt document, but I have not been able to generate numbers in the format I want.

The format I want:

```
(000,000,000)
(000,000,001)
(000,000,002)
(000,000,003)
...
(000,000,100)
...
(000,001,000)
...
(001,000,000)
...
(100,000,000)
...
(255,255,255)
```

Note: Numbers must be between 0-255.

My code:

```py
file = open("numbers.txt","w")
numbers = [i for i in range(256)]
file.write(numbers)
file.close()
```

Comment: Do you mean all combinations?

Comment: Use `itertools.product(range(256), repeat=3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do what you want. Note that this produces a pretty large file (there are 256^3 possible values, more than 16 million).

```py
import itertools


with open("numbers.txt", "w") as f:
    for color in itertools.product(range(256), repeat=3):
        f.write("({:03d}, {:03d}, {:03d})\n".format(*color))
```

Note that you should use a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) block context manager to read from and write to files, as it automatically closes the files afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply so this with three nested loops:

```
for a in range(256):
    for b in range(256):
        for c in range(256):
            print("(%03i,%03i,%03i)" % (a,b,c))
```

Note the formatting for leading zeros. And there are the `itertools` for a more efficient way:

```
import itertools
for item in itertools.product(range(256), repeat=3):
    print("(%03i,%03i,%03i)" % item)
```

Comment: Let's avoid using [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) as a variable name

Comment: Ack - that's not a clever choice :)